# Check to see of current clicked element equals to previous clicked element-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items displayed in a container with a dropdown associated with every container.A snippet of how the container list looks:

http://jsfiddle.net/jHpKB/2/

When I click on the button , the dropdown menu shows up, however, when I try to click on any other button button, the dd stays and does not hide. the list is dynamically created. What I was trying to do is if the current clicked element is same as that of the previous clicked elemnt, then hide the first dd menu
Is there way to check if a clicked element is equal to the previous clicked element in javascript(no jquery)

code:

```
afterRender: function() {
   this.el.on('click', function(e) {
     //here i want to check (if e.getTarget() === secondClickedEment) { //do something}          
   },this);
}
```

is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: you can hide all then just show the one clicked, if it is already click do toggle

Comment: thats exactly my question, how to check the condition to even add the toggle class..im hiding all on render and show only one on click..

Answer (score 0):

You can test object equality with jQuery using the **is** function. Requires 1.6 or higher.

```
var stuff = $('#stuff');
var thing = stuff;


if (stuff.is(thing)) {
    // the same
}
```

So for your situation this should work:

```
afterRender: function() {
   this.el.on('click', function(e) {
       var clickedElm = $(e.getTarget());
       var secondElm = $(secondClickedElm);
       if (clickedElm.is(secondElm)){
           // same elements
       }                   
   },this);
}
```

Comment: Sorry using only javascript, no jquery

Comment: @sarah `this.el.on('click', function(e) {` in your code this is jQuery isn't it?

Comment: its extjs/javascript code-not jquery, but im looking for a simple js function to execute this one(does not have to be in extjs)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to dynamically add/remove a class to the div, indicating if it's open or not. Then on click, you could just toggle that class.

Example:

```
let containers = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for (let i=0; i<containers.length; i++) {
    let button = containers.item(i).getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
    let menu   = containers.item(i).getElementsByClassName('menu'  )[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        menu.classList.toggle('open');
    });
}
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.open {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for what condition would it be for me to show/hide a class, the one shown above does not work for me

Comment: Are you using jquery? You can just toggle a class:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery example:

use `var lastClicked;` to hold the last clicked element, then each click check if the same one clicked then reset the `lastclicked`, otherwise update the `lastclicked`.

```js
var lastClicked;
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
  if (this == lastClicked) {
    lastClicked = '';
    $(this).children('.menu').hide();
  } else {
    lastClicked = this;
    $('.menu').hide();
    $(this).children('.menu').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #333;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">

  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="option1 option">option1</div>
    <div class="option2 option">option2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button">

  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="option1 option">option1</div>
    <div class="option2 option">option2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button">

  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="option1 option">option1</div>
    <div class="option2 option">option2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```